# What are the differences between the german nouns for 'event'?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, noun

There are many nouns that describe an event, occation, or happenings

They all can be translated to either;
* der Anlass
* das Geschehen
* das Geschehnis
* das Ereignis
* die Veranstaltung

How do I know which one I should choose?

Comment: You forgot "Event". :) In fact, "Eventmanager" is a profession.

Comment: Any good dictionary should help you to choose the appropriate translation for a given context: http://de.pons.eu/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=event&l=deen&in=&lf=en

Comment: It really depends on the context, like for all words that might be translated in different ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Der Anlass

Literally this is "the reason" (for an event), not the event itself.

Example:
At the party the project's leader says:

> **Der Anlass** für unser Treffen ist die Fertigstellung des Projekts. Das wollen wir jetzt feiern!

Translation: "**The Reason** for out meeting is the completion of the project. This is what we want to celebate now."

---

### Das Geschehen

Literally this is "the happening".

> Erwin war nur zufällig im selben Lokal. Von seinem Platz an der Bar aus beobachtete der **das Geschehen**.

Translation "Erwin was in the restaurant by accident. From his place at the bar he watched **the event**."

---

### Das Geschehnis

This is bad German, nobody uses this word. Forget it. Use »das Geschehen« instead.

---

### Das Ereignis

This is, what best matches to "the event". It can be a planned event or an event that happens by accident.

**planned**

> Die Nasa plant morgen eine Rakete zu zünden. Ich habe mir dieses **Ereignis** schon im Kalender eingetragen.

Translation: "Nasa is panning to ignite a rocket tomorrow. I already noted this **event** in my calendar.

**accidentally**

> Das **Ereignis** das den Tsunami ausgelöst hat war ein Erbeben.

Translation: "The **event** that triggered the tsunami was an earthquake."

---

### Die Veranstaltung

This is a planned event that must be prepared and where people meet. This can be a music-gig, a party, a play in a theater, a political demonstration or something similar.

> Zu der **Veranstaltung** in der *Veranstaltungshalle* werden 80.000 Besucher erwartet.

Translation: "80.000 visitors are expected to the **event** in the *banquet hall*."

---

### Das Event

### Der Event

(can be used in both forms: maskulin and neuter; both have the same meaning)

We use the english word "Event" as a foreign word in german sentences. (In German kontext you must use uppercase letter for the first letter because it is a noun.) But the meaning is not exactly the same as the english original. The english original fits best to »das Ereignis«, not to »das Event«!

We use »das Event« more as a synonym to »die Veranstaltung«.

So you can say this in German:

> Zu dem **Event** in der großen Halle kamen nur 50.000 Besucher.
>   In einer Woche wird das neue Einkaufszentrum eröffnet. Dieses **Event** will ich nicht versäumen.

Translations:
"Only 50.000 Visitors came to the **event** in the big hall."
"The new shopping-center will be opened in one week. I won't miss this **event**."

But this is a wrong usage of »das Event«:

```
Das Event, das den Mann tötete, war die Explosion einer Bombe.
```

Use »das Ereignis« instead:

> Das **Ereignis**, das den Mann tötete, war die Explosion einer Bombe.

Translation: "The **event**, that killed the man was the explosion of a bomb."

Comment: Just thought I'd add this: One other usage of *event* is in the theory of relativity. There the German equivalent is also "Ereignis", e.g. event horizon is "Ereignishorizont" in German.

Comment: Like so often, it looks like "event" came to us through  marketing activities. You know, a "Fahrkartenschalter" sounds shabby and boring, hence we better go to a "Reisecenter". Likewise, a "Veranstaltung" is not something cool people go to, you can attrackt them better when you announce an "Event" (which has a connotation of "thrilling").